# How do I parse wikitext using built-in mediawiki support for lua scripting?

Tags: lua, mediawiki

The wiktionary entry for faint lies at https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/faint

The wikitext for the etymology section is:

> From {{inh|en|enm|faynt}}, {{m|enm|feynt||weak; feeble}}, from
>   {{etyl|fro|en}} {{m|fro|faint}}, {{m|fro|feint||feigned; negligent;
>   sluggish}}, past participle of {{m|fro|feindre}}, {{m|fro|faindre||to
>   feign; sham; work negligently}}, from {{etyl|la|en}}
>   {{m|la|fingere||to touch, handle, usually form, shape, frame, form in
>   thought, imagine, conceive, contrive, devise, feign}}.

It contains various templates of the form {{xyz|...}}

I would like to parse them and get the text output as it shows on the page:

> From Middle English faynt, feynt (“weak; feeble”), from Old French
>   faint, feint (“feigned; negligent; sluggish”), past participle of
>   feindre, faindre (“to feign; sham; work negligently”), from Latin
>   fingere (“to touch, handle, usually form, shape, frame, form in
>   thought, imagine, conceive, contrive, devise, feign”).

I have about 10000 entries extracted from the freely available dumps of wiktionary [here](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiktionary/latest/).

To do this, my thinking is to extract templates and their expansions (in some form). To explore the possibilites I've been fiddling with the lua scripting facility on mediawiki. By trying various queries inside the debug console on edit pages of modules, like here:

https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Module:languages/print&action=edit

```
mw.log(p)
>> table

mw.logObject(p)
>> table#1 {
  ["code_to_name"] = function#1,
  ["name_to_code"] = function#2,
}

p.code_to_name("aaa")
>>

p.code_to_name("ab")
>>
```

But, I can't even get the function calls right. p.code_to_name("aaa") doesn't return anything.

The code that presumably expands the templates for the etymology section is here:
https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Module:etymology/templates

How do I call this code correctly? 
Is there a simpler way to achieve my goal of parsing wikitext templates?
Is there some function available in mediawiki that I can call like "parse-wikitext("text"). If so, how do I invoke it?

Comment: The `code_to_name` and `name_to_code` functions in Module:languages/print output a syntax-highlighted table. To convert a code to a name, use the table returned by [Module:languages/code to canonical name](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Module:languages/code_to_canonical_name). The console uses Lua 5.1, so to see the value of an expression, put an equals sign before it: `= p.code_to_name("aaa")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand templates (and other stuff) in wikitext, use [`frame.preprocess`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto/Lua_reference_manual#frame:preprocess), which is called as a method on a `frame` object. To get a `frame` object, use [`mw.getCurrentFrame`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto/Lua_reference_manual#mw.getCurrentFrame). For instance, type `= mw.getCurrentFrame():preprocess('{{l|en|word}}')` in the console to get the wikitext resulting from `{{l|en|word}}`. That currently gives `<span class="Latn" lang="en">[[word#English|word]]</span>`.

You can also use the [Expandtemplates action](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Expandtemplates) in the [MediaWiki API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page) ( `https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=expandtemplates&text={{l|en|word}}`), or the [Special:ExpandTemplates](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Special:ExpandTemplates&wpInput=%7B%7Bl%7Cen%7Cword%7D%7D) page, or JavaScript (if you open the browser console while browsing a Wiktionary page):

```
new mw.Api().get({
        action: 'parse',
        text: '{{l|en|word}}',
        title: mw.config.values.wgPageName,
    }).done(function (data) {
        const wikitext = data.parse.text['*'];
        if (wikitext)
            console.log(wikitext);
});
```

If the [`mw.api`](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/js/#!/api/mw.Api) library hasn't already been loaded and you get a TypeError ("mw.Api is not a constructor"):

```
mw.loader.using("mediawiki.api", function() {
    // Use mw.Api here.
});
```

So these are some of the ways to expand templates.